# start rollout to production button not visible

Tags: android, google-play-services

following warning showing me . what is the reason how can solve it please help me. what we missed at the time of publishing app

```
Unoptimized APK
Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Google requires apps to be build/delivered as Android App Bundle (AAB). You can use APK for testing, but not for releasing to the Play Store anymore.

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle